# switch pro controllers bluetooth raspberry pi steam link not working

Tags: debian, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, debian-buster, steam-link

I have the following setup:

- 3 switch pro controllers paired with blueman bluetooth
- Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.2
- Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
- latest steam link to my windows 10 pc

as long as I have only 2 controllers connected, everything is working very smoothly, we can play games well. no lag no nothing.

But as soon as I try to connect the third controller (no matter the order), none of the other controllers work properly anymore, after a minute one of the controllers gets lost and does not work in game anymore.

Any idea on how to fix this and help me connect the third and 4th controller?